# Java - Inject Bean inside method

Tags: java, cdi, inject, dwr

I want to inject bean inside my method. I have remote method(Direct Web Remoting) and i need to inject some bean inside this method. I can't use @Inject annotation in field declaration section because it will not work. It is even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible using serious bytecode instrumentation, but that's probably not feasible.

Does DWR prevent you from using regular Injection?

Comment: What do you mean "regular injection" ? I can't do something like this:
class X {
@Inject
private MyBean myBean;

  public void myMethod() {
    // myBean is null there
  }
}

Comment: If that won't work, then you're out of luck. Even if there was a way to inject beans into a method, it wouldn't work in this case either.

Comment: shame I will have to somehow get around this problem. Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do something like this.  What container do you run?  DWR doesn't seem to support CDI yet.

Apache DeltaSpike has a way you can manually inject beans.  One way is to do a call like this:

`EchoService echoService = BeanProvider.getContextualReference(EchoService.class, false);`

Another is to enrich the actual class at runtime.  Take a look at getBeans in `BeanManager`.

Comment: Thank you John! i used BeanManager as you said and everything works perfectly :)

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer :-) Also, upvotes are greatly appreciated.  Glad it helps.