# CDI: @Produces method is not injecting after invoking Instance with an AnnotationLiteral

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm trying to resolve a CDI managed bean by invoking it through an AnnotationLiteral:

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<FacesI18nService> services;

public FacesI18nService produceFacesServiceProgrammatically(Domain domain) {    
    return services.select(new DomainQualifier(domain)).get();
}
```

The `DomainQualifier` is just a standard AnnotationLiteral implementation:

```
public class DomainQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<I18nResource> implements I18nResource {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Domain domain;

    public DomainQualifier(Domain domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    @Override
    public Domain value() {
        return domain;
    }

}
```

The problem is that I *do* get a new `FacesI18nService` which is produced through the corresponding `@Produces` method. However, `@Inject`'d members of the `FacesI18nService` are always `null`

```
@Produces
@I18nResource
public FacesI18nService produceFacesService(InjectionPoint ip) {

    for (Annotation a : ip.getQualifiers()) {
        if (a instanceof I18nResource) {
            Domain domain = ((I18nResource) a).value();
            return new FacesI18nService(new I18nService(domain, databaseBundleService));
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find any matching qualifier");
}
```

**So, what am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.. got it *shame*

In order to produce CDI managed beans, one should not instantiate the return value but rather pass it into the method as parameter and return this paramter as result.

```
@Produces
@Dependent
@I18nResource
public FacesI18nService produceFacesService(InjectionPoint ip, @New FacesI18nService ret) {

    [...]

    ret.setI18nService(new I18nService(domain, databaseBundleService));
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly not true.  Is the parameter of your `@I18nResource` annotation `@Nonbinding` ?

Comment: Yes it is `@Nonbinding`. Why do you say this is not true? The given answer works for me.

Comment: No, actually what's happening is you're returning back an already injected instance.  Looks like you select `DomainQualifier`, is this class an annotation literal for the `I18nResource` annotation?

Comment: See my OP: `public class DomainQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<I18nResource>` - so yes. Actually in my real code I'm using `@New` for the `FacesI18nService` also. When I instantiate a new `FacesI18nService` in the producer method and return that, members will not be injected. When returning the supplied `@New FacesI18nService`, the members in this instance are injected.

Comment: I know this is just a blog post - but this guy is basically doing the same thing: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-producer-methods-tutorial (see 6. Producing CDI managed beans)

Comment: I see.  The reason that this works is that you're using `@New` which has been deprecated by the CDI E.G..  The correct way to make this work is to manually call injection.  You can see some prior examples I've given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977050/java-inject-bean-inside-method/18992959#18992959 which is implemented as https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L59 for reference.  I would recommend DeltaSpike to help here.

Comment: What would be the CDI 1.1 way to do this if I don't want to use DeltaSpike?

Comment: Take a look at the code starting from this point: https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L98